# Angular JS : Error while getting data from typeahead

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am getting error while loading the module for angular JS in my Module, UI bootstrap here is not getting loaded despite of all the dependencies resolved.

can any one help me ?

**Fiddle Link**

https://jsfiddle.net/tvaibhav/1pucru6L/

```
var myApp = angular.module("angularTypeahead", ["ui.bootstrap"]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add ng-app to your view,

```
<html ng-app="angularTypeahead">
```

Also

```
Change javascript -> Load type - > Wrap in body
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/1pucru6L/1/)**

Comment: i have included your changes in my project but it is still giving me error of Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]. Also, you have mentioned two ng-App still it worked can u tell me ?

Comment: @vaibhav it works! no need to mention ng-app only change the fiddle settings https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/1pucru6L/9/

Comment: @Sanjeetharan thanks a lot, actaully It was a mistake that I overlooked, <script> tags for the bootstrap was wriiten as <scipt> which was creating a probelem.Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

correct angular boostrap  **scipt** tag as script

Answer (score 1):

In your situation you need to use ng-app in html tag.

```html
<html ng-app="angularTypeahead">
```